# Optimising MySQL settings

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit confused about which settings to change in my my.conf file to optimise for my server (the mysql server keeps crashing due to our high traffic).

Here's the my.conf file:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile = 0
max_connections = 300
key_buffer = 32M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1G
join_buffer_size = 10M
read_buffer_size = 10M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
table_cache = 4000
thread_cache_size = 286
interactive_timeout = 25
wait_timeout = 7000
connect_timeout = 10
max_allowed_packet = 16M
max_connect_errors = 10
query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_size = 12M
query_cache_type = 1
tmp_table_size = 16M
skip-innodb
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 8192
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M
[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 64M
sort_buffer = 64M
read_buffer = 16M
write_buffer = 16M
[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

And the server specs are:

```
CPU Cores   2 cores
RAM (Memory)    1GB
SSD (Disk Space)    20GB
```

Running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Here are my partitions:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
vda              20G            
├─vda1 ext4     476M /boot      
├─vda2 swap     477M [SWAP]     
└─vda3 ext4    19.1G /
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by investigating the cause of the crash and defining what actually happens or crashes in a bit more detail.

Comment: I think you need to talk to you manager and get them to get you some MySQL education - you desperately need it. How can we help you optimize your environment when you haven't presented any metrics indicating what the problem is ? You should read http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6074/do-you-have-a-checklist-that-can-help-me-ask-a-better-question and it's linked documents. You need to gather evidence to support your investigation. This http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/ is relevant to you too.

Comment: I'm having some trouble locating the error logs. Both  var/log/mysql.err and /var/log/mysql.log  are empty.

Comment: In that case you need to start by enabling logging

Answer (score 1):

Not really much to say here with a generalised question like this. It would be helpful to actually know what was happening when it crashed, so the next time it happens, connecting and having a look at the process list could be a good way to go. I'd then start by enabling the slow query log and analysing long running queries (or even more verbose logging in general), taking note of diskspace/ram utilisation at the time. You can start playing around with settings and tweaking, but this would be moreso to improve performance rather than solve a problem with crashing. You also haven't elaborated on "crash"; does mysql die or does it just get stuck on a query etc?